# no conf inside $CATALINA_HOME

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7, config

I have installed tomcat7 using:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7 tomcat7-admin
```

On checking for the $CATALINA_HOME using :" ps aux | grep catalina", I get the following output: ********catalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat7*****. This clearly shows that the $CATALINA_HOME fis in /usr/share/tomcat7.

Surprisingly, on doing ls there, I dont find any conf folder. What may be the issue

```
nish@styx:/usr/share/tomcat7$ ls
bin  defaults.md5sum  defaults.template  lib
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes catlina home points right but there is no means of a tomcat.conf file in a default and plain vanilla Tomcat installation. You however can find several configuration files in the /conf folder. Details/manuals about those can be found at the [Apache Tomcat Configuration Reference.](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/index.html)

And you should always check your etc directory for configuration files.

Hope this helps.